# Extract dimensions from one field using PHP in WPAllimport

Tags: wordpress, dimensions, wpallimport

I would like to extract dimensions length, width and height from a single value 51x51x21cm into 3 separate fields using PHP in the Wordpress plugin WPAllimport.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Menno

Answer (score 0):

I use WP All Import frequently and it sounds like you will need to do one of the following:

- Reformat your data in a spreadsheet software (i.e Microsoft Excel)
- Using WP All Imports custom function editor, create a custom PHP function to split the data into 3 separate values and use their inline PHP syntax to output each value accordingly

If you have experience with PHP, the custom function editor mentioned above should be at the bottom of the "Edit Import" page when creating or editing an import. You can find more about the custom function editor [here](https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/custom-code/overview/).